# Can I use Solr instead of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, solr

I am working on one web project and more I am thinking about design of data layer the more I think that big part of it can be used directly from Solr.

For instance, faceting and count operations instead mapreduce,loop counts or $inc in MongoDB.

Solr is called "search" solution but as I said, it looks to me more like "db" solution.

Im "confused" with overlap between Solr and db solution.

Any advice from somebody who using it similary, in production ?

thanks,
Sinisa

Comment: What kind of data do you need to store, and what operations do you need to do on those data? I successfully opted to use Solr in a project to do only text analytics (no searching), but I had very specific requirements on data and operations.

Answer (score 0):

Solr is for searching. It is not designed to be a resilient or reliable datasource in the same way as a normal database, nor can it handle the types of relations a database can. There is, for example, no way to specify foreign keys or enforce constraints.

Solr does not support 'nested' datatypes in the way mongoDB might. E.g. in a document database, you can have:

```
{
  id: 123,
  title: "cat toy stores",
  stores: [
    {
      name: "cats'n'stuff",
      address: "123 cat street"
    },
    {
      name: "the catteria",
      address: "321 tail lane"
    }
  ]
}
```

But Solr although Solr supports multi-valued fields, it cannot represent the connection between `name` and `address`, so if these are to fields for a given entity you'll end up with something along the lines of:

```
{
  id: 123,
  title: "cat toy stores",
  store-names: [
    name: "cats'n'stuff",
    name: "the catteria"
  ],
  store-addresses: [
    address: "123 cat street",
    address: "321 tail lane"
  ],
}
```

Comment: That's true, however, mongodb doesnt have foreign key neither and only constrain is to use _id or whatever you choose to be "_id". If you are not using embeded documents and your requirement is 10 flat key/values, you are at the begining and it's again very "confusing" what to use :)

Comment: solr can store nested documents since 4.5, so the argument in this answer is no more valid read more at http://blog.griddynamics.com/2013/09/solr-block-join-support.html

Comment: I'm not currently running Solr, so I haven't kept up on its support for nested datatypes, but my answer is still generally valid: solr is for searching, not for storing relational data.

Answer (score 0):

I've used both, and while i agree that mongo is marketed as a database and SOLR is explicitly not, I do feel that minimising the number of moving parts in a system is always a higher priority than fitting in with the marketing garbage. Therefore I'd use SOLR/Lucene instead of mongo whenever possible. Especially, if you'll need to do searches immediately.

Sure, one could configure the SOLR DIH to import from mongo, but why create extra work for yourself? Just post your information into SOLR, per the sample code. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Is DIH configuration easy ? I mean how would you handle the nesting capabilities of Mongodb when compared to the all-flat model of Solr ?

Comment: There is a [tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) on DIH that makes the basic configuration a copy-paste job, @jplot